# Issue regarding strrev() function in C++ language

Tags: c++

I wrote a code to check if a string is a Palindrome or not. I assume logically my code is correct but the usage of strrev() function is incorrect. Please can anyone view it once? Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char name[100];
    int result;
    cout<<name<<endl;
    result=strcmp(name,strrev(name));

    if(result==0){
        cout<<"YES";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"NO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `name` is not even initialized. It does not hold any string whatsoever, it holds garbage value. So you should first either take user input using `cin >> name;` or just explicitly initialize it at point of declaration using `char name[100] = "yourString"`

Secondly, `strrev` will *reverse* the given string before returning it. So when you do `strcmp(name, strrev(name))`. `strrev(name)` already reverses the *actual* `name` string before `strcmp` can execute. So you're always comparing the same strings. You should compare a *copy* of `name` instead.

Like so-

```
char name[100], temp[100];
std::cin >> name;
strcpy(temp, name);
```

Now you should be able to print the result like before-

```cpp
if (result == 0)
{
    std::cout << "YES\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "NO\n";
}
```

Also, off topic but you don't have to explicitly store the result, you can directly compare the `strcmp` result like so -

```cpp
if (!strcmp(name, _strrev(temp)))
{
    std::cout << "YES\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "NO\n";
}
```

Or you could use ternary operator -

```cpp
std::cout << strcmp(name, _strrev(temp)) ? "NO\n" : "YES\n";
```

Here's the full program-

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    int result;
    char name[100], temp[100];
    std::cin >> name;
    strcpy(temp, name);

    std::cout << strcmp(name, _strrev(temp)) ? "NO\n" : "YES\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Last but not the least, **please** consider not using `strrev`, it is a very old C standard function. You should use `std::reverse` instead and operate using `std::string` instead of C-Style strings. If you *still* want to keep using C style strings, use `_strrev` if that is available to you.

More info on [C and C++ style strings](https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/strings.html)

Comment: Thank you, sir. I got my answer.

Comment: @Rudra Welcome to StackOverflow, if you believe you've found your solution, use the tick mark next to the answer to indicate it as accepted. This helps future viewers of this question find the solution

Answer (score 2):

`strrev` is not a standard C function, so it is anyone's guess as to what it actually does. In case if it operates on the passed string in-place then the construction `strcmp(name,strrev(name))` is wrong as it will always return 0 (the strings are equal). And, of course, the fact that you don't initialize `name` is also an error.